# Можно ли перед вызовом метода вызвать другой метод?

Tags: c#, .net

Допустим, есть некоторый класс и перед вызовом некоторых методов я хочу вызывать другой метод.

Например, хочу проверить привилегии на данную операцию.

Да, я могу в каждый метод добавить функцию, которая будет это делать.

Но можно ли сделать это другим путем?

Comment: PostSharp смотрели?

Comment: Не знаком с C#. Но очень похоже что вы ищете то что называется AOP (aspect-oriented programming).

Comment: [Атрибуты](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/z0w1kczw.aspx)?

Comment: Во первых, наследование, метод так сказать в лоб, во вторых паттерн Декоратор, как его прикрутить вопрос другой, способов множество, а вот потом уже можно и на всякие аоп смотреть.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете использовать либо [PostSharp](https://www.postsharp.net/), либо сделать самостоятельно с помощью руководства «[Intercepting method calls in C#, an approach to AOSD](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8436/Intercepting-method-calls-in-C-an-approach-to-AOSD)».